# Alias columns in the WHERE/GROUP BY clauses with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I would like to produce a query similar to the following in Entity Framework Core:

```
SELECT ID, Name, ..., (SQUARE(Color.STX - 0.1) + SQUARE(Color.STY - 0.2) + SQUARE(Color.Z - 0.3)) AS ColorVarianceSquared
FROM Point
WHERE ColorVarianceSquared < 10000.0 AND ...
ORDER BY ColorVarianceSquared
```

The schema for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Point (
    [ID]             UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Name]           NVARCHAR (64)    NULL,
    ...
    [Color]          [sys].[geometry] NULL,
);
```

(the Color column is initialized from C#/EF as an instance of `NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point`)

The use case for my question is ordering the results by how close the colors match (CIELAB color space is used).

Is there a way to create an alias column such that it can be used in the ORDER BY clause or do I have to repeat the distance formula calculation? I understand that even bare SQL cannot use an alias column in the WHERE clause, so a derived table may have to come into play somewhere, or in the worst case write the distance calculation three times - in the SELECT, WHERE, and ORDER BY. From EF perhaps I could Select() into another object and caching the distance value there, then query/order against that? Something like:

```
NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point ReferenceColor = ...
double MaximumVariance = ...

context.Point.Select(m => new {
   ID = m.ID,
   Name = m.Name,
   ...
   ColorVariance = m.Color.Distance(ReferenceColor),
})
.Where(m => m.ColorVariance < MaximumVariance && ...)
.OrderBy(m => m.ColorVariance)
.ThenBy(...)
```

To complicate things, the color matching and other WHERE conditions are added dynamically using Expressions based on parameters bound in a Controller method, so the ideal solution would involve perhaps Expressions and reflection to only add this functionality to the query if requested. While not strictly part of my question, I also wonder if adding all that wouldn't be less efficient than simply repeating the distance calculation and if it's not requested by the user, it won't get added to the WHERE clause (again, built dynamically based on user input). In other words, selecting it but not using it in the WHERE or ORDER BY may cause less of a slowdown in the database server than adding this complication to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

move your query to a `subquery` then filter your results.

```
SELECT t1.ColorVarianceSquared FROM 
    SELECT ID, Name, ..., (SQUARE(Color.STX - 0.1) + SQUARE(Color.STY - 0.2) + SQUARE(Color.Z - 0.3)) AS ColorVarianceSquared
    FROM Point) as t1 
WHERE t1.ColorVarianceSquared < 10000.0 
ORDER BY t1.ColorVarianceSquared
```

For faster query.

```
 SELECT t1.ColorVarianceSquared FROM 
        SELECT ID, Name, ..., (SQUARE(Color.STX - 0.1) + SQUARE(Color.STY - 0.2) + SQUARE(Color.Z - 0.3)) AS ColorVarianceSquared
        FROM Point
        WHERE (SQUARE(Color.STX - 0.1) + SQUARE(Color.STY - 0.2) + SQUARE(Color.Z - 0.3)) < 10000.0) as t1    
    ORDER BY t1.ColorVarianceSquared
```

Comment: I could do that, but would selecting a subquery on a large table (with no filtering), then filtering that new table be less efficient than filtering the main table? I'm not suggesting it is, and perhaps the SQL engine will optimize it away, I'm just thinking of possible performance issues.

Comment: you can put your filter inside your subquery. Please see updated answer.

Comment: True, but then the calculation is repeated, which I'm sure isn't the worst thing but again I'm wondering if it can be done without repetition and still be efficient. Also it has to be originated by EF since I don't want to write bare SQL.